# i have an unhandled exception in asp.net

Tags: arcgis-server, asp.net, arcgis-10.0

i am going to create a website and load a gis map to it.

i am using arcgis 10 and i created a web application in arcgis server 10

i created a new WebSit in visual studio 2010 and add a map resource manager.

add a MapResourceItem for this.

after that add a map control and set MapResourceManager property.

i config ArcGISIdentity too.

but unfortunately when i run application occurs this error

> Error processing server request
>
> [SoapException: Error processing server request]
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +4159
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +328
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ArcGISServer.MapServerProxy.ComputeScale(MapDescription MapDescription, ImageDisplay MapImageDisplay) +117
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.MapFunctionality.GetScale(Envelope extent, Int32 mapWidth, Int32 mapHeight) +564
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.Map.get_Scale() +794
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.Map.setExtent(Envelope value, Boolean addSetExtentCallbackResult) +2556
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.Map.set_Extent(Envelope value) +39
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.Map.validatePrimaryMapResource() +2586
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.Map._OnLoad(EventArgs e) +115
>      ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.Map.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +37
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +134
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +232
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +232
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3412

Answer (score 3):

copy your project in inetpub => wwwroot folder.wwwroot folder usually located in (C:\Inetpub\WWWRoot) .then build project